# Payflow test always giving error RESULT=26&RESPMSG=Invalid vendor account

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I am doing one test project  for PayFlowPro integration. I have used proper Vendor, Partner, Password but still getting same error.

```
RESULT=26&RESPMSG=Invalid vendor account
```

With same Vendor, Partner, Password I am able to login through manager.paypal.com but through application getting always error "RESULT=26&RESPMSG=Invalid vendor account"

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This is unlikely to be a problem we can diagnose. Contact PayPal support.

Comment: what is your email for Payflow and PayPal account?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have special characters in your password field. If you do have, try to reset it to alphanumeric only and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the issue, it was IP address issues, solved